# How to debug old Elastic Search site plugin (arrayformat)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to get an Elasticsearch plugin named "arrayformat" (https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-arrayformat) installed in Elasticsearch 2.3.5.  I think that this is a site plugin, which is why I am trying this on Elasticsearch 2.3.5.

The ZIP file didn't have a plugin-descriptor.properties, so I created one and also created an empty "_site" directory at the same level.

After that I was able to install the plugin, but it seems like it is not being found.

If I do a search for http://:/.../_search?pretty, I get results back, but if I do a search for http://:/.../_search_arrayformat?pretty, I get:

```
{
  "_index" : "bank",
  "_type" : "account",
  "_id" : "_search_arrayformat",
  "found" : false
   }
```

I'm not that familiar with ES or with ES plugins so I am not quite sure how to debug this problem.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: It seems this plugin is not supported in `ES 2.3.5`! Check out their supported ES versions [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-arrayformat/tree/1.4.0.0#versions)

Comment: @avr - ah, ok.  Any idea what would be needed to update this to ES 2.3.5?  Should I create a new question for that here?  Why can I not mark that as an answer above?

Comment: Updating plugin may not be easy as both are belongs to a different major versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin seems outdated and it only supports following ES versions `1.4.0, 1.3.1 and 1.2.1` as per it's [documentation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-arrayformat#versions)